# Need to perform an if statement inside a php foreach loop

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I'm working with the Filemaker API - which is similar to sql - basically its pulling data from a fields and from a list.

I'm trying to set up an if statement inside my foreach loop so that it adds a the tag selected="selected" to my select option in my html

Here's the code

```
<?php

$layout =& $fm->getLayout('Leads');

$values = $layout->getValueList('LeadStatus');

$list_menu = '<select name="LeadDocStatusSelect">';



foreach ($values as $value) 
    {
    $list_menu .='<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>' ;
    }


$list_menu .= '</select>';
echo $list_menu;
?>
```

How can I add an if statement like this to the foreach loop?

```
if ($businessJudgements == 'No') {
    echo 'checked="checked"';
} else {
    echo '';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of the `foreach` loop is simply a block of statements so you can put in as many as you want, such as with:

```
foreach ($values as $value) {
    $list_menu .='<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
    if ($businessJudgements == 'No') {
        echo 'checked="checked"';
    } else {
        echo '';
    }
}
```

However, are you sure you have the right attribute for the `option` tag? If it's your intent to select a specific option, `checked` is not the right method (it's meant for checkbox input fields). The `selected` attribute is the correct one for the HTML `option` tag.

So you would be better off with something like:

```
# The default is orange.

$default_value = "orange";

# Process every option.

foreach ($values as $value) {
    # Add [<option value="X"].

    $list_menu .= '<option value="' . $value . '"';

    # Add [ selected] ONLY for default one.

    if ($value == $default_value) {
        $list_menu .= ' selected';
    }

    # Add [>X</option>].

    $list_menu .= '>' . $value . '</option>';
}
```

This will give you the `option` tags as desired but the one where the value matches the default value will also have the `selected` attribute attached.

Assuming `$values` held the array `{"red", "black", "orange", "yellow"}`, you would end up with (formatted nicely here for the purposes of the answer):

```
<option value="red">             red    </option>
<option value="black">           black  </option>
<option value="orange" selected> orange </option>
<option value="yellow">          yellow </option>
```

Comment: The ; allows me to add the if statement to the variable?

Comment: @user3795995, you're not adding an `if` statement to the *variable.* Rather you're running an `if` within the `foreach` to slightly modify the list menu that you're building up. See my second code segment for one way to do this.

Comment: Ahhhh this makes sense! I did know that selected is the correct attribute. Does it need to be 'Selected ="Selected"'  ?

Comment: @user3795995, not for HTML, just `selected` on its own will be fine. XHTML forbids minimisation so *that* would need `selected="selected"`.

Answer (score 0):

I assuming that you already know how to get your  $businessJudgement , so that code should be something like this

```
<?php

$layout =& $fm->getLayout('Leads');

$values = $layout->getValueList('LeadStatus');

$list_menu = '<select name="LeadDocStatusSelect">';



foreach ($values as $value) 
    {


    if ($businessJudgements == 'No') {
     $list_menu .='<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>' ;
} else {
     $list_menu .='<option value="' . $value . '" selected >' . $value . '</option>' ;
}


    }


$list_menu .= '</select>';
echo $list_menu;
?>
```

Comment: As the code sits, that use of `echo` inside the loop is quite counterproductive. EDIT: Better now.